# Background color following text in more lines

Tags: css, background

I want to make my background follow the width of my text on every line. So instead of following the box I want the background color to follow the width of the text on each line.

E.g.:

```
--------------
| This is    |
| the normal |
| behaviour. |
--------------

-----------
| This is |____
| what I want |
| to happen |
-------------
```

Is this in anyway possible in CSS?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an even easier solution:

```
p {
    background: red;
    display:inline;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zz7z2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this but it's ugly

```
<span>sad asda sdas</span>
<span>sad asda sdas sadsd ad s</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
    background: green;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zz7z2/